# Need help with AR8161 and i217v ethernet drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel

I recently changed the motherboard in my 14.04 server.  It has two NICs:  Intel i217V and Atheros AR8161.  I could never get the Intel to work, so I shut it off in bios.  The AR8161 works, but it is unreliable. I understand that the Atheros uses the alx driver and Intel developed their own.

How can I verify that my installation is using the most reliable drivers?

```
sudo modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     15100F26458C5B941F93EBF
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        3C:74:D8:78:9C:AA:5E:CB:12:DD:D1:AA:C2:15:E1:2C:62:FC:AC:A5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

lsmod| grep alx
alx                    27531  0 
mdio                   13559  1 alx
```

Answer (score 0):

This page says it's the homepage of the driver alx: http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx It further says it was updated on March 05, 2013. It refers to the git tree here: https://github.com/erikarn/alx As you can see, it was last changed two years ago. I therefore suggest that you have the latest (old) driver version.

According to modinfo, there are no manipulable parameters in the driver. You might, however, see if you can see the errors here:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e eth0 -e alx | tail -n25
```

As the output is lengthy, I suggest you paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Perhaps there is a change in the router or BIOS that will help. I am especially suspicious about this since the usually reliable Intel doesn't perform well either.

I don't see much about your interfaces that is troubling, however, I'd be certain the selected IP address is outside the DHCP range used in the router and you might simplify it a bit: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9752880/

Also, what are your instability symptoms?

With more information, I will edit this answer and propose a solution.

Comment: Thank you @chili555. I read some posts indicating that the alx driver was not included in the kernel and it was necesary to compile it and add it. I gather from your answer, that the alx driver is in my kernel and it is the latest (although old).  I also gather that the latest must be the most reliable?

Comment: The Intel NIC never worked, so I disabled it in BIOS.  I'll give that a try next.  I would prefer to use the Intel if possible.

Comment: The output from the command above is here:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/9706475/.   I gather that looks good?

Comment: I did notice dropped packets on the the AR8161:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/9706486/.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Without a lot more information, we don't know if dropped packets are a significant problem. I see that it has an IP address but is passing no traffic. Is this a static IP address you set up? In Network Manager? In /etc/network/interfaces? May we know the exact details?

Comment: Yes, it is a static address in /etc/network/interfaces.  Network Manager was greyed out and was confusing.  Most online advice was to just edit /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: May we see the /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9751494/  

This is currently working (no Inel NIC yet)

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thank you chili.  DHCP assignment begins at 50, so the server is outside the DHCP range.  I have also entered the MAC address in the DHCP reservation table even though it is outside the range.

Stability has been good since I replaced /etc/network/interfaces with the manually built one above.  I think I will turn on the i217v NIC and set it up the exact same way.